# How do I combine lenses which contain context?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm starting from [`authorityL`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uri-bytestring-0.2.2.1/docs/URI-ByteString.html#v:authorityL) via `authorityHostL` to `hostBSL` - I know you can combine lenses via

```
(authorityL . authorityHostL . hostBSL)
```

but that fails with `Couldn't match type ‘Authority’ with ‘Maybe Authority’`. How do I properly deal with the `Maybe` here?

Comment: Does simply adding `_Just` in between help? I can't test it currently unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah. `(authorityL .> _Just .> authorityHostL .> hostBSL)` works.

Comment: @ChristophHegemann You should probably post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `_Just` in between to only focus in on the successful results.

```
(authorityL . _Just . authorityHostL . hostBSL)
```

does the trick like it's said in the comments.